# Populate HTML Table using AJAX

Tags: node.js, ajax, mongodb, express

I am getting details from mongodb using express api and calling it using AJAX in front-end, i am able to get the details but not able to display it in a table.

I have tried appending it in a table. I have attached some code on what i have done.

The AJAX Part

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            data: {},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "http://localhost:8000/employees",
            success:function(data){
                data.forEach(element => {
                   $("#Name").append("<td>"+element.Name+"</td>");
                   $("#EmployeeId").append("<td>"+element.EmpId+"</td>");
                   $("#Designation").append("<td>"+element.Designation+"</td>");
                   $("#Email").append("<td>"+element.Email+"</td>");
                });
            },
            error:function( errorMessage)
            {
                console.log(errorMessage);
            }
        });
```

The HTML part

```
<table>
     <th>Name</th><th>EmployeeId</th><th>Designation</th><th>Email</th>
     <tr>
         <td id="Name"></td>
         <td id="EmployeeId"></td>
         <td id="Designation"></td>
         <td id="Email"></td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

I am currently getting entire output in single 
i want the data in separate  .

[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35LtW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting all the data put into the same `td` because you're only using one row.

The way your code is running is basically...

```
<td id="Name">
     <td>{value1}</td><td>{value2}</td>
</td>
....
```

You need to create rows `tr` inside the callback, instead of just appending data to the columns `td`

What you can do to fix this, is building entire rows in the `success` callback..

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    data: {},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://localhost:8000/employees",
    success:function(data){
        data.forEach(element => {
            var row = document.createElement("tr");
            var name = document.createElement('td');
            var employeeID = document.createElement('td');
            var designation = document.createElement('td');
            var email = document.createElement('td');

            name.innerHTML = element.Name;
            employeeID.innerHTML = element.EmpID;
            designation.innerHTML = element.Designation;
            email.innerHTML = element.Email;

            row.appendChild(name);
            row.appendChild(employeeID);
            row.appendChild(designation);
            row.appendChild(email);

            $('#table').append(row);
        });
    },
    error:function( errorMessage)
    {
        console.log(errorMessage);
    }
});
```

and in your HTML, just apply the ID to `table` or whatever you want.

Edit::
Also, syntactically, you should put the table headers inside a row as well, so,

```
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Employee ID</th>
    ...
</tr>
```